# Swift get data from Firebase before the page loads

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this piece of code:

```
@State var ustasList: Array<Usta> = []

func getUstalar() -> Array<Usta>{
    var templist: Array<Usta> = []
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.db.collection("ustas").getDocuments(){ (querysnapshot,err) in
            for document in querysnapshot!.documents {
                let data = document.data()
                let newUsta = Usta(id: UUID(), name: data["name"] as! String, type: data["type"] as! String,telephone: data["telephone"] as! String)
                templist.append(newUsta)
            }
       }
    }
    return templist
}
 var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
               List{
                    ForEach(0..<self.ustasList.count){ i in
                        Text(self.ustasList[i].name)
                    }
                }
        }
        .onAppear(){
            self.ustasList = self.getUstalar()
        }
  }
```

The purpose of this code is to first retrieve all the data in "usta" collection. Then assign it to ustaList and finally to show the elements in `ustaList` in `List`. However, `getUstalar` takes some time to execute, hence List doesn't show anything. How can I ensure that List shows the data after the ustaList is updated. Usually swift automatically, does it but in this case, it doesn't update.

Comment: I'm not sure how it works in swift, but normally we use an await keyword to ensure that data already arrives. https://stablekernel.com/article/would-asyncawait-work-in-swiftios/ should help in your understanding of how this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to wrap the statement in a `Group` and use an `if` to check wether content is available or not. Be sure to use the `onAppear`on the `Group`. Like this (Tested and working on iOS 13.5):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var stringArray: Array<String> = []

    func getSomeInformation() {
        // Wait for 2 seconds then append items
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            self.stringArray.append("a")
            self.stringArray.append("b")
            self.stringArray.append("c")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Group { // Group all
            
            if self.stringArray.count > 0 { // Use if statement to check for content
                NavigationView() {
                    List() {
                        ForEach(self.stringArray, id: \.self) { item in
                            Text(item).foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.onAppear() {
            self.getSomeInformation()
        }
    }
    
}
```

There is a way around to use this without a `Group` and `if` statement. Use `id` inside of the ForEach Statement to allow it distinguish and update the view if changes to `@State` occur like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var stringArray: Array<String> = []

    func getSomeInformation() {
        // Wait for 2 seconds then append items
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            self.stringArray.append("a")
            self.stringArray.append("b")
            self.stringArray.append("c")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView() {
            List() {
                ForEach(self.stringArray, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text(item).foregroundColor(Color.black)
                }
            }
        }.onAppear() {
            self.getSomeInformation()
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know how you did it, but before when i wanted to change value of an array in DispatchQueue through self... = , it gave me an error about mutating. This time it dind't give it to me.